# URL showing wordpress directory - Can I remove this?

Tags: database, wordpress, url

I have wordpress installed in a directory entitled 'wp'.
When I access my site then this is displayed in the URL.

eg. the about us page
will display:

```
http://www.domain-name.com/wp/about
```

Can I change this so that the 'wp' is not displayed?

to become simply:

```
http://www.domain-name.com/about
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: That is the hosting company.  What is the web server?  Apache?  IIS?

Comment: @robert Apache - dont know which version

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the root of www.domain-name.com to /wp/ (relative to what it's now).

Comment: can you tell me how to do that please

Comment: check out your hosting company's site. most of those companies use something like Plesk and it will let you change your root folder really easily.

Comment: An other option is to put it in the root folder (so in the folder that the wp folder is currently located in.

Comment: The hosting company said this: As I have told you the Pleask we offer is only on the VPS or Dedicated servers. You have installed the application from the free apps menu so you cannot change the URL as you wish. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: in that case you should find an other hosting company.